# Launching a service from msi installer that depends on assemblies installed by the msi

Tags: windows-services, windows-vista, wix, windows-installer, privileges

I'm using WiX to write a MSI installer to start a service that depends on DLLs installed by the MSI. On Vista, the DLLs become added to the global assembly cache in the MSI's `InstallFinalize` phase, so I can't use the built-in service starting command in WiX. That one tries to start the service before the DLLs are in the GAC, and fails. The solution seems to be to use a custom action instead [1], and run that after `InstallFinalize`.

The custom action I used was starting the service with `sc`. Everything works fine when running the installer as an administrator, but running as a regular user doesn't work. The installer will elevate privileges for the actual install phase, but will drop them after finalizing the installation, and starting the service with `sc` as a non-privileged user will fail. Setting the custom action to be deferred and no-impersonate to get admin privileges won't work either after `InstallFinalize` [2].

As a final kludge, I tried to add `<Condition>Privileged</Condition>` to the WiX file to tell the user that the installer needs to be run as Administrator, but I couldn't get that to work either. The `Privileged` value gets set to 1 during the installation, maybe when the main install sequence is given higher privileges.

So has anyone else ran into the combination of Vista, non-Administrator user, installer needs to start a service and service needs stuff that goes into GAC during installation to run? Is there any kind of working general approach to this?

[1] http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg09162.html

[2] http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg15381.html

Comment: Can your service be started with non-administrative privileges (i.e. by a normal user) at all? If it is a system service this is most likely not the case. Or am I misunderstanding your problem and you install as Administrator but don't get an elevated token for starting the service?

Comment: The service needs to do things that require administrator privileges, so no, it can't be run by a normal user. Everything works when installing as Administrator (say, from an Administrator console), the problem is getting it to work with privilege elevation when running the installer as a normal user.

Comment: If the service requires administrative privileges to be started than a normal user won't be able to start it so I guess you are out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those times when the easiest solution is just to schedule a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few possibilities :

- If possible, do not install prerequisite assemblies in the GAC. This will allow your service to be started normally (ie between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize).
- Create a bootstrapper (a small app that launches prerequisite MSIs in a certain order). Place the prerequisite assemblies (those that go in the GAC) into their own MSI, and get the bootstrapper to install them before it installs your service.
- Create a launcher (an even smaller app that just launches your MSI). Give it a manifest that will make it run elevated. That way, the entire MSI is elevated, not just the part that's between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize. You should be able to invoke `sc` succesfully.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @sascha. Rebooting is not just the easiest but cleanest in this case. All of the other proposed solutions are going to set you up for a much higher failure rate in the future. IMHO, the Windows Installer design w.r.t. the GAC is busted. The reboot is recognition of that.